# Write a list then reverse it returning

Tags: python

Write a list of 5 numbers then another list with the values reversed...

Solution 1 works. Solution 2, not so much.

```
counter = 0
count2 = 0
list = []
otherlist = []

import random

#Solution 1
list = random.sample(range(1, 100), 5)
otherlist = list.reverse    

#Solution 2
while counter<5:
    list.append(random.randint(5,10))
    print(list[counter])
    counter = counter + 1

counter = counter - 1

while counter > (-1):
    templist.append(list[counter])
    print(list[counter])
    print("Real",templist[count2])
    counter = counter - 1
    count2 = count2 + 1
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also, don't forget to ask an  actual question.

Comment: Also, suggest you don't use `list` as a variable name as this hides the builtin `list` type. Note: `list.reverse` does not reverse the list without `()` on the end. Are you opposed to `for` loops for a reason, e.g. `for counter in range(5):`? Also, other than missing `templist = []` somewhere how else does it not work?

Comment: Also, `list.reverse()` returns `None`. It reverses `list` in-place. `otherlist` is hence `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reverse a list, do as follows:

```
# Solution 1
alist = random.sample(range(1, 100), 5)
otherlist = list(reversed(alist))

# Solution 2 (My favourite)
otherlist = alist[::-1]

# Solution 3
otherlist = alist[:]
otherlist.reverse()

# Solution 4
otherlist = []
for i in range(len(alist)-1, -1, -1):
    otherlist.append(alist[i])

# Solution 5
counter = count2 = 0
alist, templist = [], []
while counter<5:
    alist.append(random.randint(5,10))
    print(alist[counter])
    counter += 1

while counter > 0:
    counter -= 1
    templist.append(alist[counter])
    print(alist[counter])
    print("Real",templist[count2])    
    count2 += 1
```

Comment: Already +1ed but maybe add some explantion for why you need to use the the `copy()` in solution 3.

Comment: @shash678 copy the origin list to avoid to change it, `[:]` is better than `copy()`

Comment: I was talking about like how you use `[:]` or `copy()` so that so you don't just copy the reference to the list but instead the actual list. Anyway good answer.

Comment: For solution 5, I have no idea why yours works and mine doesn't other than the index of the counter being off. i fixed that but still the list doesn't reverse

Comment: @user3042850 you should define `templist=[]` before the second while.